# Actions module - redirect to url

Tags: 8, redirection, actions

I'm trying to learn about the functionality of this module, however I don't understand quite right what the *Redirect to URL* option means/does. Any hint in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Redirect to URL" means that when the action is executed the user will be taken to the specified URL.

This action does exist in Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ya.tech. I thought of that from the beginning, but how do I trigger that action?

Comment: In D7/D6 you there is a core module called Trigger, which works like a UI for matching events and actions. In D8 that module has been removed. So that you can only trigger this action from you custom code or maybe with the help of some contributed modules (Rules?).

Comment: Note that some other D8 actions can be used in Views bulk operations.